# mapping container-ship returns False when it should be True in dbt

Tags: jinja2, dbt

In my [dbt](http://getdbt.com) macro, I am passing a dictionary argument which looks like
`random_mapping={"<string1>":"<string2>","<string3>":"<string4>"}`

Now, when I check if a given string is a key in my `random_mapping`, it returns `False`, I used [`log`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/log/) and checked my `dbt.log` file and it looks right.

Below is how I am checking [container-ship](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators)

`dbt_utils.string_literal(relation) in random_mapping`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it on my own. But, I hope this helps someone else.

The environment I was working on was `jinja` in `dbt`

`dbt_utils.string_literal(relation)` returns a string with quotes like `'<some_string>'`, whereas we wanted `<some_string>`.

This can be resolved simply by using `strip` function on a string, so it would look like `dbt_utils.string_literal(relation).strip("\'")` for my case.

Note: `\'` is used because `'` escapes when alone.